# SSRS - 401 error after deploying the application

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have uploaded rdl files created on VS 2013 and SQL Server 2014 to reportserver of SQL Server 2016.

In my existing application reports are rendering properly, however after deploying the application on IIS, I am getting below error. What may be the reason?

> WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized
>
> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods() +192
>          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname) +51
>          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String methodname) +12
>         Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute(RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod) +449
>          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ListRenderingExtensions() +90
>          Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.ListRenderingExtensions() +16
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.ListRenderingExtensions() +59
>   ASP.reportdashboardviewerwebform_aspx.ReportViewer_OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) +60
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +131
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having a similar problem. Did you try setting up a specific User Account in the IIS -> ApplicationPool -> Identity for your site?
Does this User Account have sufficient rights on your SQL Server?